# My JQuery Animation Wont expand from the center

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, alignment, jquery-animate

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/JayFreelances/fcm1255c/1/#&togetherjs=Bsj91cv0Sy)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".button").click(function(){
        $(".circle-div").animate({width: "300px"});
    });
});
```

I am trying to may the div expand in width 300px. When I wrote it, it only expands to the right, rather than the center from the p tag. What am I doing wrong?

It worked when I was messing around at [W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_eff_animate) and just centered the div and changed width to height, but it won't work in my workspace?

Answer (score 0):

Need to add a container for it and center align the content inside, so that when it expands it seems like it is expanding from the center.

Check if this helps -

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    
    $(".button").click(function(){
        $(".circle-div").animate({width: "300px"});
    });

    
});
```

```css
p {
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: white;
    background-color: yellowgreen;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 15px;
    left: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 4px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

p:hover {
    color: #f0f;
}

.circle-div {
    background-color: green;
    border-radius: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    width: 50px;
}

.container {
    bottom: 3.49%;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
 <div class="circle-div"> 
      <p class="button">+</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's still very off center. Someone actually helped me center it but only in jsfiddle, but when I p;lace it in another workspace it continues to be off center.

Comment: <div id="circle-lmt">
            <div class="circle-div"> 
                <p class="button">+</p>
            </div>
          </div>

$(document).ready(function() {
 "use strict";
    $(".button").click(function(){
    
        if($(".circle-div").width()!==300) {
            $(".circle-div").animate({width: "300px"});
    
        } else {
            $(".circle-div").animate({width: "50px"});
    }
    });
    
});